# Facebook auth.logout and auth.authResponseChange events do not fire when logging out via fb:login-button

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, logout, xfbml

I am using the fb:login-button in an ASP.NET MVC web application. Initially I was setting autologoutlink="true" but now this attribute appears to have been deprecated by Facebook as it is no longer listed in the documentation.

When I do supply it, the button does change to "Logout" and does indeed log me out of Facebook, but my attempts to subscribe to either auth.logout or auth.authResponseChange do not work- neither fire (auth.login works fine though).

What is the current recommended way for the user to log out of my site and Facebook?

Or is Facebook trying to avoid people logging out at all?

I have seen many recommendations to first check if the user is logged in and if so, to not even render the FB login button at all. In any case I need to get a hook into the Facebook logout to redirect to my own Logout page to perform my own actions on the server.

Comment: At the risk of sounding cheeky it does say on the discontinued Facebook developer forums: "Many Facebook engineers actively participate on Stack Overflow, along with many of the best Facebook developers, making Stack Overflow one of the best places to get help with your technical questions." I just want clarification on whether one can still achieve login AND logout purely via the XFBML login button. Or do I have to use the Javascript API logout function?

Comment: I have culled the fb:login-button and switched to exclusively using the Facebook Javascript API. I am rendering a Login, Logout or Register button based on the result of a FB.getLoginStatus call and subscribing successfully to auth.login and auth.logout raised by my calls to FB.login() and FB.logout(). I would still like to know what Facebook's official position / recommendation re logging out is, but I have made a very clear explicit Logout button as it's what users deserve. Aside from numerous unsettling random script errors from within Facebook's libraries, it seems to work.